# Invalid procedure call or argument error vb 6

Tags: dictionary, collections, vb6

I have the following code:

I am getting the error in counts.Item(value) = 1.

```
Set xmlNodeList = xmlEncounter.documentElement.selectNodes("//BillingLIne/Receipts")

If xmlNodeList.length > 1 Then
    For i_Loop1 = 1 To xmlNodeList.length
        strserviceChecked_GL(i_Loop1) = xmlNodeList.Item(i_Loop1 - 1).Attributes.getNamedItem("ServiceID").nodeValue
        Id1tobechecked_GL(i_Loop1) = xmlNodeList.Item(i_Loop1 - 1).Attributes.getNamedItem("Receptid1").nodeValue
        Id2tobechecked_GL(i_Loop1) = xmlNodeList.Item(i_Loop1 - 1).Attributes.getNamedItem("Receptid2").nodeValue
        Id3tobechecked_GL(i_Loop1) = xmlNodeList.Item(i_Loop1 - 1).Attributes.getNamedItem("Receptid3").nodeValue
        Id4tobechecked_GL(i_Loop1) = xmlNodeList.Item(i_Loop1 - 1).Attributes.getNamedItem("Receptid4").nodeValue
    Next i_Loop1
End If

Dim value As Variant
    Dim counts As Collection
    Set counts = New Collection
    For Each value In strserviceChecked_GL
        If Not Exists(counts,value) Then
            counts.Item(value) = 1
        Else
            counts.Item(value) = counts.Item(value) + 1
        End If
    Next


Public Function Exists(ByVal oCol As Collection, ByVal vKey As Variant) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
oCol.Item vKey
Exists = (Err.Number = 0)
Err.Clear

End Function
```

Comment: You are probably receiving that message because `counts` is a new (empty) collection and you are trying to set an item in it.  You first need to add a new item to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

When a collection has no item for a key, you need to add one, and give it a value as follows.

```
For Each value In strserviceChecked_GL
    If Not Exists(counts,value) Then
        ' Key 'value' is not in 'counts' collection.
        ' Add key 'value', and give it the value 1.
        counts.Add 1, CStr(value)
        'counts.Item(value) = 1
    Else
        counts.Item(value) = counts.Item(value) + 1
    End If
Next
```